# How to select values from different rows in same table based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with entries as below. I would like an output which will show the DAYS as DAYS from rows having TYPE = 'medium' which have the corresponding CUST-SUPP combination. Is this possible in Oracle SQL? If so how?
[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible in Oracle or in any relational database. Rows do not have inherent ordering. If you want to generate this number, you'll need to indicate a very specific ordering criteria. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.CUST, o.SUPP, o.TYPE, m.DAYS
FROM table_name o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CUST, DAYS
           FROM table_name
           WHERE TYPE = 'medium') m
ON o.CUST = m.CUST;
```

where table_name is the name of your table